# "read ECONNRESET" on MYSQL with self hosted server and vps hosted database

Tags: mysql

I have FiveM server hosted locally, and hosted server with mysql database.
Mysql queries are executed for a few secounds, then i have to reset resource because it returns
'read ECONNRESET' error.

My friend is also using this same database, and also hosting hes server on local-host, he has no problems with the connection tho.

```
[script:ox_core] SCRIPT ERROR: @ox_core/server/player/registry.lua:22: ox_core was unable to execute a query!
[script:ox_core] Query: SELECT `userid` FROM `users` WHERE steam = ?
[script:ox_core] ["1100001160f0742"]
[script:ox_core] read ECONNRESET
```

I've tried switching database to other server but error continues.